# Why is $r^2-9=0$ the characteristic equation for $y'-9y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to learn how to solve second order differential equations and I don't understand something here:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SecondOrderConcepts.aspx

Question says find two solutions to $y'-9y=0$

It then says the characteristic equation is:

$r^2-9=0 \Rightarrow +-3$ and I understand why $-3$ and $3$ are the solutions, but not the equation.  So before I can understand the two solutions I just need help understanding the characteristic equation.

I'm specifically confused at how $ar^2+br+c=0$ is related to $r^2-9=0$?  I would think it would be $r-9=0$ since $y'$ is the first derivative.

Sorry if this is a silly question!

Comment: The characteristic equation for your ODE is *not* $\;r^2-9=0\;$ but rather $\;r-9=0$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo so it's a typo on the website?

Comment: Apparently so, though reading on I can see they have the general case correct later in that page.

Comment: If you click the image it expands it enough to see that it is, in fact, $y''$.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Happy it wasn't a lack of understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. $r^2-9=0$ should be the characteristic polynomial of $y''-9y=0$. It seems like the display on that site is not very good, it is supposed to be $y''$ instead of $y'$

Answer (score 1):

At first, observe that $y(x) \equiv 0$ solves the equation. Then the usual ansatz for such equations for $y \not \equiv 0$ is $y(x) = Ae^{\lambda x}$ with $\Bbb C \ni A \neq 0$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb C$, since this gives you constant coefficients when you derive. Assuming, that you mean the equation $y''-9y=0$ (since you said second order ODE), you have to insert the ansatz into the equation:

$$A \lambda^2 e^{\lambda x} - 9Ae^{\lambda x} = 0$$

Since $Ae^{\lambda x} \neq 0$ for all $x$, we may divide and obtain

$$\lambda^2 - 9 = 0,$$

which is the characteristic equation for this ODE.